# How to inspect traffic from PC on domain?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, domain, windows, teamviewer

Is there a tool (on Microsoft domain server, or 3rd party) that can allow me to log if some domain user is generating specific traffic at chosen time (in my case, I want to know if he is using Team Viewer for Incoming traffic)?

Domain server is on MS Windows 2008 R2, and PCs are on Win 7.

Thanks very much.

Comment: Why not log it at your firewall/router?

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a job for something like Wireshark.